# Creating a Jquery slidein menu

Tags: jquery, css

Good morning, I would like to do a floating slidein menu similar to this website using Jquery (bottom right hand side: https://www.casumo.com/)

Can someone give me a direction of how I can do it properly please? This is my first time doing something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `position: fixed;` to position the menu where you want it to appear and to toggle a class controlling the menu's height when you click some element of the menu. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu h4', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UZFuT/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick variation of *my* menu at Casumo.com, that I threw togheter for you :)

http://jsfiddle.net/q8X2d/5/

You could do some calculations before sliding in the menu as well:

```
$(".menu-wrapper").hover(function() {
    var $menu = $(this).find(".menu");
    var menuHeight = $menu.outerHeight();
$menu.stop().animate({ top: -menuHeight }, 200);
}, function() {
    var $menu = $(this).find(".menu");
    $menu.stop().animate({ top: 0 }, 200);
});
```

If you need any more help customizing it, swing by our office in Ta'Xbiex ;)